# Draw a free-form shape and mark it with a curved line

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw the shape shown in the image below:
[image]

After several attempts, I reached a good result

```
\documentclass[border=8mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\tikz \draw[dashed] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(1,1.5)(3.5,0.9)(4.8,0)(6,1.3)(7.2,2)(7.5,3.5)(6,4)(4,5)(2.6,3.5)(1,3)} node at (2,1.6) {$B_r(x)$};
\fill[lightgray] (-4,3) circle[radius=12mm] node [text=black,yshift=20mm] {$U$};
\fill   (-4,3) circle[radius=1mm]  node [above,font=\small] {$c$};
\draw   (-4,3) -- node [above,font=\small] {$r$} (-2.8,3);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that I cannot create an arrow curve as shown in the figure below

```
\draw[->] (1) to [out=315, in=315, looseness=2.5] (2);
```

[image]
I need the rest of the shape to be a light color different from the color of the circle

[image]
Is it possible to improve the shape further so that it matches the first image?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You may delete your [old question on the same topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/698134/123129). Note: You could have also just made an edit to the old question.

Comment: You can play with the [`tension` value](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#tikz/tension) to change the curvature of the plot (it's basically the looseness of the plot. Give the B_r(x) node a name and use it as the starting point with a [to\[bend left\]](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#sec-74.3) path, for example. Choosing the same angles for `out` and `in` is certainly not producing such a path, more like `out=45, in=135`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good idea to use `smooth cycle`, but polar coordinates may make imitating the shape easier. Instead of drawing your circle, make it a `node` so you can draw to its border. The `bend left` option for `draw` can make your curved arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed, fill=gray!10] plot [smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates {(0:2.8)(30:4)(60:3)(100:3.5)(135:3)(205:3.5)(270:1.4)(315:2.8)} ;
\node[draw, dashed, fill=gray!50, circle, minimum size=20mm, label={[label distance=5mm]105:$U$}](C) at (0,0)  {};
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=2pt]  node[above] {$c$};
\draw (C.center) -- node[below] {$r$} (C.0);
\node (B) at (205:2.5){$B_r(x)$};
\draw[->] (B) to[bend left=45] (C.180);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Adaptations

- don't use `\tikz` inside `tikzpicture`
- give B_r node a name `(br)` to use it later for the arrow
- define a `\coordinate (c)` for the circle
- draw arrow with:

  ```
  \draw[->] (br) to [out=90, in=160, looseness=1.5] ($(c)+(160:10mm)$);
  ```
- use option `fill=lightgray!30` for coloring the shape

#### Code

```
\documentclass[border=8mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    \draw[dashed, fill=lightgray!30] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(1,1.5)(3.5,0.9)(4.8,0)(6,1.3)(7.2,2)(7.5,3.5)(6,4)(4,5)(2.6,3.5)(1,3)};
    \node (br) at (2,1.6) {$B_r(x)$};
    \coordinate (c) at (5,2.3);
    \fill[lightgray] (c) circle[radius=10mm] node [text=black, yshift=10mm] {$U$};
    \fill (c) circle[radius=1mm]  node [above, font=\small] {$c$};
    \draw (c) -- node [above, font=\small] {$r$} ++(10mm,0);
    \draw[->] (br) to [out=90, in=160, looseness=1.5] ($(c)+(160:10mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it, which reuses part of your code.

Some remarks:

Region U is tricky. I tried `to[out=..,in=..]` but that's not nice code in the end. So I assigned new coordinates and `tension=1`.

I moved (refactored) some, not all, formatting statements into the style section. This way you change it in one position only, like colors. Should you consider using fill patterns, which may not be a good idea nowadays, put them here, too.

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Triangle},%                      arrow tip; try als {Stealth} etc.
        arr/.style={->,line width=1.5pt},%  arrows style
        UF/.style={dashed,fill=gray!20},%   style of U-area
        CF/.style={color=black!60, fill=white!65, very thick},
    ]
```

The arrow is made quite simple, while a to `to[bend left]` might have worked, too:

```
    \draw[arr] (B) to [out=80,in=140] +(30:2.2);
```

Think of having had a straight line there before; the end point I set arbitrarily, as with the pahtes chosen the circle doesn't belong to a node:

```
    \draw[arr] (B) -- +(30:2.2);
```

Had it been the shape of a node, you could have used positions like (M), (M.west), (M.120) etc. and it will end at said positions.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}%             already loaded, see class
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}%   has many nice arrow tips

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Triangle},%                      arrow tip; try als {Stealth} etc.
        arr/.style={->,line width=1.5pt},%  arrows style
        UF/.style={dashed,fill=gray!20},%   style of U-area
        CF/.style={color=black!60, fill=white!65, very thick},
    ]
    % ~~~ area U ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[UF] plot [smooth cycle,tension=1]
        coordinates {(0.5,.5)(0,2)(1.5,3)(2.5,5)(5,4)(7,3)(6,.5)(4,.5)}
        node at (3,4) {$U$};;
    
    % ~~~ circle ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (M) at (4,2);%      saves typing
    \filldraw[CF] (M) circle (1);
    \draw[fill=black,line width=1.2pt] (M) circle (1mm) 
            node [yshift=3mm] {$c$} --
            node[yshift=+2mm,xshift=0mm] {$r$} +(1,0);
            
    % ~~~ B ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (B) at (1,1) {$B_r(x)$};
    
    % ~~~ arrow ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[arr] (B) to [out=80,in=140] +(30:2.2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: Here's an example from changing the styles to this:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Triangle},%                      arrow tip; try als {Stealth} etc.
        arr/.style={->,line width=1.5pt,blue},% arrows style
        UF/.style={dashed,fill=gray!10},%   style of U-area
        CF/.style={color=black!60, fill=gray!65, very thick},
    ]
```

[image: new style]